# Why can´t you set the value of a destructured html element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a useRef and it is "pointed" to a HTML input element:

```
const testRef = useRef()
...
<input ref={testRef} />
```

And I have a function that should clear the value of the input element (It takes a HTML element as argument.):

```
const handleClear = ({ name }) => name = ""
...
handleClear(testRef.current)
```

This is not working but when I am not using "destructuring" it workes fine:

```
const handleClear = (element) => element.name = ""
...
handleClear(testRef.current)
```

I can´t explain this to me.

Comment: When you take just `name` it doesn't retain reference to where it is. It's just the value in isolation. If you change it, all you're doing is changing the local variable called `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `element` is really just an `object` with it's values being a list of properties and functions.

**Something like this:**

```js
{
    name: "..."
    href: "..."
    addEventListener: (...) => ...
}
```

When you use destructuring assignment you are taking one of these properties **in isolation**.

**Like this:**

```js
let object = {
    name: "..."
    href: "..."
    addEventListener: (...) => ...
}

let name = object.name
```

So when you modify `name` nothing happens to object.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of how argument destructuring works. When you use the `({ name }) => expr` syntax, it's actually syntactic sugar for something like:

```js
(_obj) => {
    let name = _obj.name;
    delete _obj; // imagine you lose access to the `_obj` variable
    return expr;
};
```

Therefore when you do `name = value`, you're changing the scope's parameter variable, not the actual `_obj.name` field.